# Python: CSV Reader Key Errors, But if I add extra key value it works

Tags: python, csv

I'm finding it hard to describe this issue. Basically if I add a header to my csv file, my script runs fine but my values get messed up. If I change the name of the first key value, it sometimes works fine or if I swap the first two, it works. It is as if there is a ghost header somewhere in my csv file.

Here is the Error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\workspace\xx\uploader\user_db_and_upload.py", line 111, in <module>
    csv_dict_reader_and_upload(f_obj)
  File "C:\Users\x\workspace\xx\uploader\user_db_and_upload.py", line 83, in csv_dict_reader_and_upload
    name = data_in_list[x]['name']
KeyError: 'name'
```

Code :

```
import json
import csv
import requests

def csv_dict_reader_and_upload(file_obj):
data_in_list = []
x=0

reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')

for row in reader:
    data_in_list.append(row)
    name = data_in_list[x]['name']
    phone = data_in_list[x]['phone']
    email = data_in_list[x]['email']
    dept = data_in_list[x]['department']
    office = data_in_list[x]['office']
    role = data_in_list[x]['role']

    data = {"user": {"name": name, "email": email, "user_fields": { "department": dept, "job_title": role, "office_location": office, "phone_number1": phone}}}
    payload = json.dumps(data)
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 422:
        print('Duplicate Found', response.status_code, 'Moving to next record...')
    elif response.status_code != 201:
        print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Problem with the request. Exiting.')
        exit()

    x= x+1

    print(name + " has been uploaded.")
    time.sleep(0.5)
return data_in_list
```

Here is the CSV File Headers and first row:

```
name,email,phone,office,department,role

----------- ---------,---------,-----,------,----,----

John Smith,jsmith@website.com,'00000000,Winchester,Accounts,Credit Controller
```

Comment: you have an open quotation mark but no closing one here: '0000000,....

Comment: Fixed, but still having same issue.

Comment: Try putting the fieldnames in your DictReader constructor and omitting the header `reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, fieldnames=['name','email','phone','office','department','role'])`

Comment: That worked. Thank you. And just to clarify, why did this work, any idea? And can i still refer to the variables in the upload?